# CodeDeploy fails on BeforeBlockTraffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

AWS CodeDeploy Fails on Hook BeforeStopTraffic after a wait and I have no logs or details.

I am assuming its some sort of issue communicating with the EC2 instance, but I have nothing to go on.

The CodeDeploy Agent is up and running and Port 443 is open on output.

I would also assume that if it was a permissions issue, I would be told something, but Nada!!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the failure is a script from last successful deployment that fails. To resolve this  create a deployment of the application where your getting BeforeBlockTraffic and AfterBlockTraffic failure should be ignored.

Use CodeDeployment console to create a deployment page, under *ApplicationStop lifecycle event failure*, choose *Don't fail the deployment to an instance if this lifecycle event on the instance fails.*

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the EC2 instances not having the right IAM role assigned.

Annoying as you don't get any pointers to this, but trail and error resolved this in the end

Comment: Please provide guidelines to resolve the original question.

Comment: when creating EC2 instances that will be used with Code Deploy, there is an extra option to attach an IAM role to manage the instance. 
When just spinning up normal EC2 instances, you don't use this option, but for CodeDeploy to have access to the EC2 instance to update it, you need to create an IAM role for the EC2 instance that will allow CodeDeploy access to the instance.
This is not obvious as the errors you get don't mention this and the option to attach an IAM role is in the advanced options for the EC2 instance set-up

Comment: Which role needs to be attached? Please be specific.

Comment: You need to Create a roll in IAM with two sets of policies.

AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore is an AWS one, and you need to create a policy with

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}